# NSDateFormatter with Unix Computer time value

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

Is it possible to use an NSDateFormatter to convert between Unix time i.e. `1334688300703` to an NSDate?

I'm using Magical Record to import records and trying to use the dateFormat user attribute to convert.

If not I'll just do the conversion manually.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a date formatter for that.

Use

```
NSDate *theDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unix_time];
```

or

```
unix_time = [theDate timeIntervalSince1970];
```

respectively.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that method. I was just trying to use the auto import methods that Magical record provides. I guessed that I'd have to do it manually though, I was just trying to be lazy :)

Answer (score 1):

The NSDate instance method

```
- (id)initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)seconds
```

would appear to be your best bet.

Comment: Care to share a bit of your experience with this? It's not getting the job done?